# Network Error Fetching Resource in Axum Server During Video Download Task

Tags: javascript, node.js, rust, rust-axum

I'm developing a web application using Rust's Axum framework and have encountered a network error when trying to implement a video download feature. The issue arises when my server-side function, which handles video downloads, is called. Removing this function resolves the error, suggesting the issue is related to how the function operates.

**Environment:**

- Rust with Axum framework
- JavaScript (client-side)

**Problem:**
When I trigger a video download from the client side (using JavaScript `fetch` to send a POST request), the server (Axum in Rust) throws a "network error fetching resource." This error does not occur when I remove the video download handling function on the server.

**Server-side code snippet:**

```rust
use axum::{
    response::{Response, IntoResponse},
    http::{StatusCode, header::HeaderMap},
    Json,
};
use reqwest::header;
use serde::Deserialize;

use crate::utils::youtube::download_youtube;

#[derive(Deserialize)]
pub struct VideoRequest {
    site: String,
    url: String,
}

pub async fn download_video(Json(payload): Json<VideoRequest>) -> impl IntoResponse {
    let response_body = match payload.site.as_str() {
        "youtube" => {
            format!("Processing youtube with URL: {}", payload.url)
        },
        "type2" => format!("Processing type2 with URL: {}", payload.url),
        _ => format!("Unknown type: {}", payload.site),
    };

    let mut headers = HeaderMap::new();
    headers.insert(header::CONTENT_TYPE, "text/plain".parse().unwrap());

    Response::builder()
    .status(StatusCode::OK)
    .header(header::CONTENT_TYPE, "text/plain")
    .body(response_body)
    .unwrap()
}
```

**Client-side code snippet:**

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const downloadButton = document.getElementById('downloadButton');
    if (downloadButton) {
        downloadButton.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault(); // Prevent the default button click action

            const videoUrl = document.getElementById('videoUrl').value;
            fetch('http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/v1/download', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
                body: JSON.stringify({ site: "youtube", url: videoUrl })
            })
            .then(response => console.log(response.status))
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Error:', error);
            });
        })
    }
});
```

**Attempts to resolve:**

- Checked CORS settings on the server (seem to be configured correctly).
- The server works fine for other routes and functionalities.

**Questions:**

1. What could be causing the network error specifically when the video download function is active?
2. Are there any best practices for handling long-running tasks like video downloads in Axum to avoid blocking or timeouts?
3. Could this be related to async handling in Rust, and if so, how can I better structure my async function to prevent such issues?

Any insights or suggestions on how to troubleshoot or resolve this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please [edit] your question. Include: 1: what  error message (if any) does the client side get (use the dev tools in your browser to capture and inspect the request), 2: what errors if any do you see in the server log (you do have a log right?). Also: you included the [tag:node.js] tag. How is node.js relevant to this question?

Comment: You're not fetching any remote resource in the server. Are you sure this is the correct code?